# Не получается изменить url с get параметром при помощи htaccess, как это сделать?

Tags: .htaccess, url

Необходимо изменить адрес `http://systemorg/?news/edit=1` на `http://systemorg/news/edit/1` . Как это сделать?

```
RewriteEngine On<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ ?news/edit=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^news/edit=(\d+)$
RewriteRule (.*)  /news/edit/%1?
```